# Autenticação REST/JAVA+ANGULAR2

Tags: java, rest, angular

Tenho uma api rest em java e preciso realizar uma autenticação (login/senha).
Estou me baseando nesse código java que utiliza Jwt: http://www.totalcross.com/blog/seguranca-com-jwt-e-java/

Minha dúvida é: como tratar esse token no angular e autenticar o usuário?
Toda fonte de estudo é bem vinda.
Desde já, agradeço..

Comment: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/

Comment: @mercador Obrigado pela resposta. Vou tentar me aprofundar mais no material, minhas dúvida mesmo está sendo em como o angular trata esse token que é retornado..

Answer (score 0):

Eu costumo acionar um serviço no meu backend que recebe um usuário e senha. Esse serviço valida e devolve um token JWT.

No angular, eu utilizo o provider $localStorage para armazená-lo. Para cada requisição que será feita para a minha API, eu busco o token armazenado no login e incluo ele nos HEADERS da requisição para validá-lo no backend.

Caso queira utilizar o token no angular para qualquer tipo de finalidade, você pode utilizar o angular-jwt para decodificá-lo com a função jwtHelper.decodeToken(token); e/ou validar através da função jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)

Ah, para utilizar esse angular-jwt você precisa adicioná-lo no module da sua app ('angular-jwt').